# UITextField not responding to touch in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, constraints

So I have multiple UITextFields in my storyboard, but there is one isolated field that will not respond to any touch (neither in the simulator nor on the device) for all iOS versions, besides on the very right side of the field? This may have something to do with the constraints/frame of the field, but I have tried resolving autolayout issues, but nothing seems to work.

This is what my storyboard looks like (with the malfunctioning UITextField selected): [image: Malfunctioning field highlighted]

And this is what the simulator looks like:

[image: Simulator]

Any ideas? There is very little functionality code-wise, so I imagine this is an Xcode formatting thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form the picture it looks like the picker is actual over the textfield. It doesn't look like it but those are rather tall. You could try panning on the text field and see if the picker moves. Also you can try hiding it and see if that changes anything.

Good luck and hope that helps.